# exception when matlab function called from java

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-compiler

I compiled matlab function using library compiler in matlab 2015b, I suspect the pca function the source of the exception, because I have made a simple function of addition and it was executed without any problems, how can I execute the pca function??

**Matlab function:**

```
function [ COEFF,SCORE,latent] = ACP( path )

 Data = fileread(path);
 Data = strrep(Data, ',', '.');
 FID = fopen('comma2pointData.txt', 'w');
 fwrite(FID, Data, 'char');
 fclose(FID);
 Data=importdata('comma2pointData.txt','\t');

[COEFF,SCORE,latent] = pca(Data);

end
```

**Java code:**

```
    String path = "/Desktop/datamicro.txt";
    Object[] result = null;
    acpClass acp = null;

        try {                
            acp = new acpClass();
            result=acp.ACP(3, path);
        } catch (MWException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CalculAcpFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } finally {

            MWArray.disposeArray(result);
            acp.dispose();

        }
```

**datamicro.txt**

```
    0,25    0,16    0,95    0,53    0,22    1,17    549,00  
    0,20    0,06    0,39    0,62    0,18    1,09    293,25  
    0,16    0,05    0,31    0,39    0,14    0,78    935,00  
    0,19    0,06    0,40    0,62    0,23    1,14    380,00
```

**The exception:**

```
  Caught "std::exception" Exception message is:
  Timed out waiting for Thread to Process
  avr. 06, 2017 11:59:57 PM microarchi_proj.Microarchi_proj main
  GRAVE: null
  ... Matlab M-code Stack Trace ...
  com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException: Timed out waiting for Thread to Process
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.mclFeval(Native Method)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.access$600(MWMCR.java:31)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$6.mclFeval(MWMCR.java:861)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR$5.invoke(MWMCR.java:759)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.mclFeval(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.invoke(MWMCR.java:427)
    at ACPFunction.acpClass.ACP(acpClass.java:210)
    at microarchi_proj.Microarchi_proj.main(Microarchi_proj.java:1145)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

After data has been provided, the code has been edited to accommodate data formatting.

The edited code is:

```
function [ COEFF,SCORE,latent] = ACP(path)
%% Reading file as a string
Data = fileread(path);

%% Converting comma decimal to point decimal values
Data = strrep(Data, ',', '.');

%% writing point decimal values to new file
FID = fopen('comma2pointData.txt', 'w');
fwrite(FID, Data, 'char');
fclose(FID);
% Delete unwanted variables
clear Data FID

%% Reading new file
nData=importdata('comma2pointData.txt','\t');

% determin rows and columns
rows = length(nData);
[~,columns] = size(strsplit(nData{1},'    '));
b = zeros(rows,columns);

% 
for row = 1:rows
line = nData{row};
a = strsplit(line,'    ');
b(row,:)=cellfun(@str2num,a); 
end

% Delete unwanted variables
clear nData a line row rows columns

%% Calling pca function
[COEFF,SCORE,latent] = pca(b);

% Delete unwanted variables
clear b

% End of Function
end
```

I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Before running the java code I have tested the function in matlab with the same datafile, so I don't think that the problem comes from my data file.

Comment: Have you seen into the issue where acp is declared with two classes i.e. pcaClass() and acpClass()?

Comment: I compiled line by line the matlab code and tested in java, the line generating the exception is this line:  `Data=importdata('comma2pointData.txt','\t');` but I don't know how to resolve it

Comment: If any row in your data file has more then one decimal point, importdata() will get data in form of strings and pass it pca() function which will ultimately create timeout exception.

Comment: And how to resolve it? My source file has commas so I have to replace comma to dot and the pass it to pca function.

Comment: can you edit your question by sharing first 10 rows of your data file?

Comment: Or alternatively run your code with the data, I have provided in my answer.

Comment: Tks @Waseem Anwar I have the same issue, I think the problem comes in the same line, if I can to load the data in the b variable without importdata function that will be better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140232/discussion-between-ouz-nour-and-waseem-anwar).